# Saving a query for azure log analytics inside a (custom) query pack using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-log-analytics, azure-rm, azure-log-analytics-workspace

In order to save a query for a log analytics workspace using Terraform we can use the
[`azurerm_log_analytics_saved_search` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_saved_search).

However, it seems that it is using the ['legacy query'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/save-query#save-as-a-legacy-query) option.

[image]

We have a policy on resource groups with obligatory tags, so creation of the default query pack fails, and I'd like to save a query to a custom query pack, is there a Terraform resource that is able to do this?

(The atm alternative is using the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/log-analytics/query-pack/query?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-log-analytics-query-pack-query-create))

minimal example:

```
# create a resource group
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "query-pack-tf"
  location = "westeurope"
}

# create a log analytics workspace
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "workspace-01"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# create a query pack
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_query_pack" "default" {
  name                = "pack-test"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = "westeurope"
}

# A resources that uploads a query to azure - there seems to be no way to save to any query pack
#-> this is the legacy way to save queries
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_saved_search" "example" {
  name                       = "example-query"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id

  category                   = "Custom Logs"
  display_name               = "Example Query"
  query                      = <<QUERY
    // Your query logic goes here
    // For example:
    AzureDiagnostics
  QUERY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using [`azurerm_log_analytics_query_pack_query`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_query_pack_query)

If you add this snippet to the code example it should save to the query pack:

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_query_pack_query" "example" {
  name          = "19952bc3-0bf9-49eb-b713-6b80e7a41847"
  query_pack_id = azurerm_log_analytics_query_pack.default.id
  body          = "let newExceptionsTimeRange = 1d;\nlet timeRangeToCheckBefore = 7d;\nexceptions\n| where timestamp < ago(timeRangeToCheckBefore)\n| summarize count() by problemId\n| join kind= rightanti (\nexceptions\n| where timestamp >= ago(newExceptionsTimeRange)\n| extend stack = tostring(details[0].rawStack)\n| summarize count(), dcount(user_AuthenticatedId), min(timestamp), max(timestamp), any(stack) by problemId  \n) on problemId \n| order by  count_ desc\n"
  display_name  = "Exceptions - New in the last 24 hours"
}
```

Then in order to find the query inside log analytics do the following:

- select Queries (right top)
- select '1 selected'
- tick the desired query pack
- go back to log analytics interface
- click dropdown and select 'query type'
- find your query pack query under 'Query pack'

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

[image]